# Filesharing between two Windows 10 devices in different networks

Tags: windows-10, data, data-transfer

I am trying to find a good way to share or move files and folders between two Windows 10 Pro devices.
My setup looks like this:
[image: Setup]

My Laptop is connected through WiFi to the company network.
My Desktop PC is standing right next to it, has 5 ethernet ports (one of them is connected to the companys private network).

I would like to connect them using a ethernet cable and find a good way to use a shared folder or a good way to move files between them, because i am tired of using USB-sticks.

Any cloud solution is not permitted by company standards.

I am administrator on both devices.

Thank you in advance for helping me with this issue.

Comment: Are you asking for a software recommendation, or, a way to solve your problem?  They may not be the same.

Comment: I am asking for a software, that can solve my problem. ideally with a short description how.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from my understanding you want to share easily transfer files between your 2 machines, from a same network which is ( indirectly connected), but have you checked if the networks use the same gateway or is there a network bridge of some sort?

In you have same gateway and you are able to ping either machine then simply create a mapped folder where you dedicate to folder transfers. Otherwise if it's different networks my suggestion would be an open source file sharing software like DC++. Then simply configure the network settings in order to share the files.

You will have to install the software on both machines though.

Edit

If you haven't found a solution you could try TeamViewer